# app crashes when empty

Tags: java, android

I've recently started learning android studio, I've made an app that shows if a number is triangular or square. The problem is when the user does not put anything into textfield, then my app crashes! Why is this happening? What do I need to change?

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    class Number {

        int number;

        public boolean isSquare() {

            double squareRoot = Math.sqrt(number);

            if (squareRoot == Math.floor(squareRoot)) {

                return true;

            } else {

                return false;

            }


        }

        public boolean isTriangular() {

            int x = 1;

            int y = 1;

            while (y < number) {

                x++;

                y = y + x;

            }

            if ( y == number ) {

                return true;

            } else {

                return false;

            }



        }


    }

    public void testNumber(View view) {

        String msg = "";

        EditText usersNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usersNumber);

        Number myNumber = new Number();

        myNumber.number = Integer.parseInt(usersNumber.getText().toString());


        if (usersNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {


            msg = myNumber.number + "Please eneter a Number!";

        } else {


            if (myNumber.isSquare()) {

                if (myNumber.isTriangular()) {

                    msg = myNumber.number + "is both square and triangular!";
                } else {

                    msg = myNumber.number + "is square but not traingular";


                }


            } else {


                if (myNumber.isTriangular()) {

                    msg = myNumber.number + "is triangular but not suqare !";
                } else {

                    msg = myNumber.number + "is neither";
                }


            }




        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your error log

Comment: why have you added ios tag? It is not obj-c or swift code !!

Comment: Just a quick hint: Put your class `Number` in its own .java-file. There is no reason to put this in your `Activity` class. And check for a [parametrized constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34775298/what-is-the-use-of-a-parameterized-constructor-in-java)

Comment: using android studio 2.2.3 btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the case the user do not enter a number in your edittext files, `usersNumber.getText().toString()` returns blank which can not be pared as a number.

That's why you get an Exception in this Statement: `Integer.parseInt(usersNumber.getText().toString());`

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) for more Details.
To stop your app for crashing, you can use a `try { ... } catch {...}` block arround your code:

```
try {
 myNumber.number = Integer.parseInt(usersNumber.getText().toString());


        if (usersNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {


            msg = myNumber.number + "Please eneter a Number!";

        } else {


            if (myNumber.isSquare()) {

                if (myNumber.isTriangular()) {

                    msg = myNumber.number + "is both square and triangular!";
                } else {

                    msg = myNumber.number + "is square but not traingular";


                }


            } else {


                if (myNumber.isTriangular()) {

                    msg = myNumber.number + "is triangular but not suqare !";
                } else {

                    msg = myNumber.number + "is neither";
                }


            }




        }
}catch (NumberFormatException ne){
  //handle the exception
}
```

or simply check for null before parsing it to an integer:

```
 if (!usersNumber.getText().toString().equals("")){
 myNumber.number = Integer.parseInt(usersNumber.getText().toString());
} else {
  myNumber.number = 0;
}
```

Comment: YES thanks THIS worked at last ! But when user enter nothing it shows  " 0 please enter a number " how can I change it to only " please enter a number "

Comment: if (usersNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
msg = "Please eneter a Number!";

Comment: Fully functional ! the way I wanted thanks for the help ;) it's my first time using this site ! was not expecting to get right answers this quickly :)

Answer (score -1):

put the code you would like into a try catch statement, this way the app will not crash if an error occurs.

```
try
{
  //Insert code here//
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  //Handle error here//
}
```

Comment: Do not catch the superclass Exception. Always catch a concrete subclass of it